# com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am getting exception when sending request with retrofit. Tried various solution, every time give malformed exception.

here is my json response

```
{
    "type": "admin",
    "user": "admin"
}
```

Model

```
public class LoginResponse {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("user")
@Expose
private String user;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getUser() {
return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
this.user = user;
}

}
```

ApiIntreface.java

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json" )
    @POST("login.php")
    Call<LoginResponse> login(
            @Field("user") String user,
            @Field("pass") String pass);
```

Api.java

```
public static ApiInterface getClient(){
    if (retrofit == null){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        retrofit = new  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

MainActivity

```
Call<LoginResponse> call = Api.getClient().login(user,pass);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

The json format is ok. still it showing same exception. I am using retrofit 2.5.0 
Thank you advance for any response.

Comment: Is your base url http or https? Try https if it's http.

Comment: but my api url prefix is http